# Integration over an open interval.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Is there any difference between the following integrations:
$$\int_a^b f(x) dx$$ where $(a,b]$

And $$\int_a^b f(x) dx$$ where $[a,b]$

Comment: Do you know a bit of measure theory?

Comment: @SineoftheTime, yes

Comment: basically, if you remove a point you're removing a set of measure zero so the value of the integral does not change

Comment: would you recommend a reference ?

Comment: What kind of integrals? Where did this question came from? Needs context.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This theorem comes from Introduction to Real Analysis
Book by Robert G. Bartle 7.1.3

> For $a\leq b$ let the $x_0=a ,x_n=b $ choose $n-1$ points in $[a,b]$ and call them $x_2 ,x_3, \dots x_{n-1}$ such that $x_k > x_{k-1}$ then make the interval $I_k:= [x_{k-1}, x_k]$ for $0 \leq k \leq n$ define the norm of that partition by $|P|= \sup\limits_{k=1}^n \{ x_{k}- x_{k-1} \}$, from every interval $I_k$ choose any point and label it $t_k$  then we can define the integral $\int_a ^b f(t) dt $ if $\forall \epsilon >0 \ \exists \delta>0$ such that if $|P|<\delta$ then $\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1}) - L \right| < \epsilon  $ for some $L \in \mathbb{R}$ that number $L $ is $\int_a ^b f(t) dt$ if $a> b $ we define $\int_a ^b f(t) dt=-\int_b ^a f(t) dt$ we call $f$ a **Riemann intergable function**

***Theorem***  If $g$ is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ and if $f (x) =g (x) $ except for a finite number of points in $[a, b]$, then $f$ is Riemann integrable and $\int _a^b f(x)dx= \int_a^b g(x)dx$

***proof***
Let $c$ be a point in the interval and let $L:= \int_a^b g(x)dx$. Assume that $f(x)=g(x)$ for all $x\ne c \in[a,b]$.
For any tagged partition $P$ , the terms in the two sums $\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1}) , \sum\limits_{k=1}^n g(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1})$ are identical with the exception of at most two terms (in the case that $c$  is an endpoint).
Therefore, we have $\left|\sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1}) - \sum\limits_{k=1}^n g(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1})\right|\leq 2|P|(|f(c) |+|g(c)|)$

given $\varepsilon>0 $ since $g $ is a is Riemann integrable on $[a, b]$ choose $\delta_1 $ st if $|P| < \delta_1$ implies $\left| 
                  \sum\limits_{k=1}^n g(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1}) -L\right| <\frac \varepsilon 2 $ and choose $\delta_2 =\frac{\varepsilon}{8(|f(c) |+|g(c)|)}$ and choose $\delta = \min \{\delta_1, \delta_2 \} $

$\left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1})-L\right|\leq \left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^n g(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1})-L\right| + \left| \sum\limits_{k=1}^n f(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1})-\sum\limits_{k=1}^n g(t_k)  (x_{k}- x_{k-1})\right| < \varepsilon$

Comment: is this theorem valid for infinit integral??

Comment: @ElmarconiAbdo do you mean improper integrals?

Comment: Yes. Does the same theory applicable for improper integrals?

Comment: Thanks for your qualified response, I am from Egypt. May I ask for getting in contact with you?

Comment: صباح الورد
من أم الدنيا

Comment: القاهرة--هندسة اتصالات،،، وانت؟

Comment: الف شكر على مساعدتك

Comment: دا تليفونى لو تسمح اتشرف بيك     01000878716

Comment: موجود على نفس الرقم

Comment: فى امكانيه للتواصل؟؟

Comment: سوري نسيت , اسمك ايه في التليجرام ؟

Comment: Yoshimitsu MK   نفس رقم الموبايل

Answer (score 4):

In the context implicit in your question the answer is "no". In the most elementary terms, the definite integral is the limit of the sums of areas of sets of rectangles that approximate the area under the graph of $f$. That area does not change if you change the value of $f$ at any finite number of  points, or omit the area "above" any finite number of  points.

This should also answer your other question at
[For an integration of a closed interval , how can we exclude a certain point from this integration?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4821879/for-an-integration-of-a-closed-interval-how-can-we-exclude-a-certain-point-fro)

Comment: would you please recommend a reference

Comment: The answer from @pie has a proof and a reference.